# Check for overlap in active JFrames

Tags: java, swing

How would I go about writing a for loop which iterated through a list of JFrames, and made sure that non were touching eachother on screen?

Pseudocode for what I'm trying to do would be:

```
for(JFrame f : frameList)
{
if(f.isTouchingOtherFramesInFrameList())
f.setLocation(shift elsewhere)
}
```

Thanks!

//side note, I'm well aware multiple JFrames is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if two JFrames overlap by checking if their bounds intersect. Here is a short example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        JFrame jFrame1 = new JFrame();
        jFrame1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        jFrame1.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        jFrame1.setTitle("JFrame 1");
        jFrame1.setVisible(true);

        JFrame jFrame2 = new JFrame();
        jFrame2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        jFrame2.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
        jFrame2.setTitle("JFrame 2");
        jFrame2.setVisible(true);

        JFrame jFrame3 = new JFrame();
        jFrame3.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        jFrame3.setBounds(400, 400, 200, 200);
        jFrame3.setTitle("JFrame 3");
        jFrame3.setVisible(true);

        List<JFrame> jFrames = new ArrayList<>(3);
        jFrames.add(jFrame1);
        jFrames.add(jFrame2);
        jFrames.add(jFrame3);

        for(int i = 0; i < jFrames.size(); i ++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < jFrames.size(); j ++) {
                if(i != j && jFrames.get(i).getBounds().intersects(jFrames.get(j).getBounds())) {
                    System.out.println(jFrames.get(i).getTitle() + " overlaps!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JFrame 1 overlaps!
JFrame 2 overlaps!
```

Comment: Any clue on how to easily determine if there is a free space on the screen to move the window to?

Answer (score 1):

For testing if two JFrames overlap each other, you can use

```
jframe1.getBounds().intersects(jframe2.getBounds());
```

Finding a new, suitable location is a trickier matter. It may not be possible, but if it is possible, you'll need some way to determine what the ideal place to move to would be